# XAML Combobox index -1

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have a combobox like this :

```
<ComboBox Style="{StaticResource ComboBox}" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="CBX_GROUP" ItemsSource="{Binding }">
      <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock>
                     <Run Text="{Binding LIBELLE}" />
                </TextBlock>
           </DataTemplate>
      </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>    
</ComboBox>
```

But when I select a value, I can't return on the index -1 because I haven't this index.

How can I put a first value with index -1 and text value "" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add item to index -1 because that means nothing is selected. You can set it in code behind `myComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;` or you can add an item on top of the list with an empty value by `myComboBox.Items.Insert (0, "");` and handle the empty selection in code behind.

Comment: Yes but I use an observable collection to put values into combobox. And when we use combobox.itemssource we can't use combobox.items.insert(0, "")

Comment: @Moussawi If you're bound to an observable collection, you would add items to the collection itself such as `myCollection.Insert(0, new MyItem())`